# Create multiple mean columns in csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, mean

I have a sheet with the values as below:

```
AirTemperature  AirHumidity SoilTemperature SoilMoisture    LightIntensity  WindSpeed   Year    Month   Day Hour    Minute  Second  TimeStamp   MonthCategorical    TimeOfDay
18  84  17  41  40  4   2016    1   1   6   1   1   10106   January Day
20  88  22  92  31  0   2016    1   1   7   1   1   10107   January Day
23  1   22  59  3   0   2016    1   1   8   1   1   10108   January Day
23  3   22  72  41  4   2016    1   1   9   1   1   10109   January Day
24  63  23  83  85  0   2016    1   1   10  1   1   10110   January Day
29  73  27  50  1   4   2016    1   1   11  1   1   10111   January Day
28  37  30  46  29  3   2016    1   1   12  1   1   10112   January Day
```

Which looks as below:

[image]

I would like to calculate the mean condition for each day (i.e. have the mean temperature for day 1,2,3,4 and mean air humidity for day 1,2,3,4). I would like to create a new csv with these values. So the output has the year, month, day, meanAirTemp, MeanAirHumidity and so on for all the conditions.

I am using the following code to get just one condition:

```
NightTimeTemperatures = pd.read_csv('MonthlyDataSplit/Night/MeanNightlyConditions.csv')
MeanMonthlyNightlyTemperatures = NightTimeTemperatures.groupby('Month')['AirTemperature'].mean().reset_index(name='MeanAirTemperature')
MeanMonthlyNightlyTemperatures.to_csv(r'MonthlyDataSplit/Day/SummaryMeanNightlyTemps.csv')
```

But I would like to expand it to do the same for all the conditions. Something like the following:

```
DayTimeTemperatures = pd.read_csv('MonthlyDataSplit/Day/MeanDailyConditions.csv')
MeanMonthlyDailyTemperatures = DayTimeTemperatures.groupby('Month')['AirTemperature','AirHumidity', 'SoilTemperature', 'SoilMoisture', 'LightIntensity', 'WindSpeed'].mean().reset_index(name='meanAirTemperature', 'meanAirHumidity', 'meanSoilTemperature', 'meanSoilMoisture','meanLightIntensity','meanWindSpeed')
MeanMonthlyDailyTemperatures.to_csv(r'MonthlyDataSplit/Day/SummaryMeanDailyConditions.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use different aggregate functions you can use `grp.agg()` function, specifying different aggregate functions for different columns:

```
print(df.groupby(['Year','Month','Day']).agg(
    {'AirTemperature': 'mean',
     'AirHumidity': 'mean',
     'SoilTemperature': 'max'
    }).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   Year  Month  Day  AirTemperature  SoilTemperature  AirHumidity
0  2016      1    1       23.571429               30    49.857143
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) with filtering columns by `subset`:

```
print NightTimeTemperatures.groupby('Month')[['AirTemperature','AirHumidity', 'SoilTemperature', 'SoilMoisture', 'LightIntensity', 'WindSpeed']].mean().reset_index()
   Month  AirTemperature  AirHumidity  SoilTemperature  SoilMoisture  \
0      1       23.571429    49.857143        23.285714     63.285714   

   LightIntensity  WindSpeed  
0       32.857143   2.142857
```